# Is there a command or way on how to retrieve or directly download a .csv file from raspberry pi to windows 7 using putty?

Tags: windows-7, raspberrypi, putty, csv

I am trying to remotely retrieve a .csv file from my raspberry pi using putty. Is that possible? If so, is there any command that allows me to automatically download or transfer that .csv to my windows pc? What command shall I run?

Comment: Is this anyway related to Ubuntu?

Comment: Read about `scp` and `rsync`

Comment: Ubuntu is linux-based, RPi is linux based.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned putty so I'm assuming you are `ssh`ing to your rpi from windows.

To transfer file, you can use `scp` which for windows is available as [`winscp`](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php).

Look into [this part](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline) for a command line, you should be able to automate it using whatever system you like in your windows.

An example would be:
`winscp.exe /defaults /keepuptodate // "C:\Users\martin\Documents\csv" /home/pi/csv`